# Visual Basic - Web Request 403 Forbidden

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am new to Visual Basic so I dont know much about Syntax e.t.c

So if anyone could help me out that be great!

Im getting a 403 Forbidden Error most likely because of the User Agent being used. The website is probably picking up that its not an actual user entering the Website and therefore blocks access.

How do I apply a User Agent that will bypass this issue? I have no idea where to put the Syntax.

My Code:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim sources(1) As String
            array(0) = "http://proxy-ip-list.com"
            array(1) = "http://sslproxies24.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default"

        For Each element As String In sources

            'Connect to the Proxy Source;
            Dim source As Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(element)

            'Prepare the Response;
            Dim response As Net.HttpWebResponse = source.GetResponse

            'Load the HTML;
            Dim reader As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
            Dim html As String = reader.ReadToEnd

            'Regex;
            Dim expression As New Regex("[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{1,4}")

            'Set the Matches variable to the Matched Sections of the HTML source;
            Dim matches As MatchCollection = expression.Matches(html)

            'Add the proxies to the ListBox;
            For Each proxy As Match In matches
                ListBox1.Items.Add(proxy)
            Next

        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: How can you be sure it's the user agent? Usually you get HTTP error 403 when you need to authorize yourself, that is, when you need to log in.

Comment: @VisualVincent I have tried scraping from the same site with PHP with the same Error and hopping on a "GoogleBot" User Agent fixed it. But I just dont know how to apply a User Agent in VB.NET

Comment: If you switch to a `HttpWebRequest` you can set it's [UserAgent property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.useragent(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @VisualVincent Its already using a WebRequest but how do I apply a User Agent?

Comment: You apply the user agent by setting the `UserAgent` property to whatever user agent you like. There's a small example in the link I provided.